# How to capture Android app log running on Android Runtime on Chrome (ARC Welder)?

Tags: android, logging, logcat, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to run my Android app on Chrome 50 / Windows 7 using ARC Welder beta. It's crashing immediately after I click on 'Test' button of ARC Welder.

I followed the approach mentioned [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices) to capture the app logs.

Though I see log getting started, it doesn't have much info. All I get is:

> --------- beginning of main
>
> --------- beginning of system
>
> --------- beginning of crash

I am new to this, can any one help me out on how to get proper app logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your manifest using the Additional Metadata option in ARCWelder: {"stderrLog": "V"}

After you've started your app open chrome://inspect/#apps and look for your app.

Click the inspect link and open the console tab.

Type the following command to see the logging: plugin.shell('logcat');

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried collecting `stdout` and `stderr` from Chrome/NaCl as suggested in the document, you can actually increase the amount of Native Client’s diagnostic output by setting these environment variables:

- NACL_PLUGIN_DEBUG=1
- NACL_SRPC_DEBUG=[1-255] (use a higher number for more verbose debug output)
- NACLVERBOSITY=[1-255]

You can also redirect stdout and stderr to output files by setting these environment variables:

- NACL_EXE_STDOUT=c:\nacl_stdout.log
- NACL_EXE_STDERR=c:\nacl_stderr.log

Furthermore, you can use to redirect Native Client’s internally-generated messages by setting this variable:
 - NACLLOG=c:\nacl.log

More tools and techniques which you can use to debug are described in [Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/debugging#controlling-the-level-of-native-client-error-and-warning-messages).

Comment: Sorry your solution is not clear to me. I am not using native client, it's just a simple android apk loaded on ARC welder.